# CRM 2011 Having created a new organization how do I change to that being the default organisation viewed via http

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a brand new server with CRM 2011 installed on it and setup a test organization and that is accessible fine over the internet via https.
I then imported an organization from my old CRM4 setup. It took hours to convert but it successfully completed and I now have the 2 organisations in my CRM deployment. 
How do I change it so the imported organization is the one viewed via the web.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to view both of the organizations installed in the 2011 environment.  When accessing the environments if you append the orgname to the url it tells CRM where which org to use.  For example if you use `https://servername/` to access your current environment you can use `https://servername/org1` or `https://servername/org2` to determine which org to connect to.

If you are looking to change the default org for the users so `https://servername/` redirects to org2 then I'm not aware of a supported way to do this.  However you can change it directly via SQL. There is an [article here](http://elsdesire.blogspot.com/2012/11/crm-2011-change-default-organization.html) that I copied the contents from.  If you don't care about a particular user then you can probably skip step #4 and just update them all assuming they are all in the new org.

1. Go to SQL Server where CRM installed
2. Find the User’s Systemuserid for that org.  You can also find the user GUID using this query on your organization's DB

   ```
   Select systemuserid from systemuserbase where domainname = ‘domain\user’
   ```
3. Use MSCRM_CONFIG

   ```
   Select * from organization where friendlyname ='<yourOrgHere>'
   ```
4. Find the User’s ID using the MSCRM_CONFIG and the ID in step 2

   ```
   Select userid from systemuserorganizations where 
   crmuserid = <Guid in step #2>
   ```
5. Use MSCRM_CONFIG

   ```
   Update SystemUser set DefaultOrganizationId = '<Guid Step #3>’ 
   Where id = '<Guid Step #4>'
   ```

Comment: Just adding a short note that this still works in CRM 2016 OnPremise organizations.